# Deploying Flask app to Heroku: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, flask, deployment

The flask runs well in my local machine. However, while I tried to deploy it to heroku, I get stuck in the deploy step:
`git push heroku master`

The error is:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'`

Thanks!

It looks heroku has successfully downloaded lxml module, I suspect there is something wrong with the path.

```
Downloading lxml-3.8.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (7.3MB)
remote:        Collecting tushare==0.8.2 (from -r /tmp/build_c53be87973e8917c338f0bc2fe032c48/requirements.txt (line 46))
remote:          

Downloading tushare-0.8.2.zip (121kB)
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-a4xb2e0z/tushare/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
remote:                import tushare
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-a4xb2e0z/tushare/tushare/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
remote:                from tushare.stock.trading import (get_hist_data, get_tick_data,
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-a4xb2e0z/tushare/tushare/stock/trading.py", line 13, in <module>
remote:                import lxml.html
remote:            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
```

Comment: Can you share the full terminal output? Looks like you've just missed adding `lxml` to your requirements.txt

Comment: Did you try installing lxml?

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-lxml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved now.

1. remove the tushare from requirement.txt, then do git commit -am "make it better" and git push heroku master, it will be pushed successfully;
2. put back the tushare into requirement.txt, redo the git commit -am "make it better" and git push heroku master.

Comment: any idea why did this happen? Even I am facing the same issue.